# GET curl request only works in postman but not in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get html as response but it only works in postman but not in php. In php I get different response like "Something went wrong..."

What I'm missing ?

Here is code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.avnet.com/shop/SearchDisplay?searchTerm=LMK316BJ476ML-T&countryId=apac&deflangId=-1&storeId=715839038&catalogId=10001&langId=-1&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&searchSource=Q&searchType=100&avnSearchType=all",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

postman response

[image]

php response

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is postman sending a user-agent header?

Comment: no, this is the same code I copied from postman and used in php script.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `curl` request from command?
Because when you execute `curl` request from command, you will get the same response as you are getting now "Something Went Wrong".

Comment: Do you execute this url alone in postman? It could be because of a previously saved cookie value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I played around the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and figured out the site is validating 2 headers which are User-Agent and Accept-Language. I sent it correctly and it worked. Please find the headers below

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36",
"Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5"
)
```

Enjoyed figuring out the issue.

Comment: My first comment on your original question was user-agent

Comment: @Dale its not my question :) . I am a contributor. It expects Accept-Language too.

Comment: Oh yea! Apologies friend /walks away in embaressment

Comment: @Dale Why won't you give me a vote for the good piece of work

Comment: My apologies @Dale, I did tried sending request with user-agent but it didn't work also tried looking into postman if it was sending any header but couldn't found any except for cache-control.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This might solve the problem:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Last night, I spent more than 3 hours to solve the similar problem and at the end, I noticed it was related with server configuration. My sysadmin solved the problem by updating configuration, as I understand, some server configuration doesn't let you send CURL request same server.

Check below ticket:
https://talk.plesk.com/threads/curl-dont-resolved-correctly-at-same-server.295173/

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Accept: application/json","User-Agent: WooCommerce API Client-PHP/3.1.0"]);
```

After spending lots of time, above Header works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining *why* the header solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

remove this
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",